# Only black window drawing Triangle, using openGL and GLUT with Xcode on MacOS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glut

Nothing shows up on my window only black solid color, the build proceeded, but nothing else happening..

Also I tried the same code on Windows, still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#else
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <GL/glew.h>        // must be downloaded
#include <GL/freeglut.h>    // must be downloaded unless you have an Apple
#endif

using namespace std;

void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(1.5, 1.5);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello, GL");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,500);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a zero-area triangle, all the vertices are in a line.  You can double-check by using `GL_LINE_LOOP` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES` or using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`.

Zero-area triangles generally don't generate any fragments during rasterization.  No fragments, nothing drawn.

Fixes:

- Pass in a non-zero-area triangle to OpenGL.
- Get rid of the `glMatrixMode()` & `gluOrtho2D()` calls, you don't need them for geometry that small.
- No need for a reshape callback that only calls `glViewport()`; [GLUT's default reshape callback already does that for you](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html).

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello, GL");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, Wow, you helped a lot, I didn't expected the problem being mathematical and not syntactical.. Now it shows me the wanted triangle in white! Thanks!